# Prove that $2\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+c}}-\frac{9\sqrt{c^2+1}}{8c}<1$ with $a;c>0$

Tags: inequality

Let $a;c>0$ such that $a^2+2ac=1$. Prove that $$2\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+c}}-\frac{9\sqrt{c^2+1}}{8c}<1$$

---

**My proof:**

$\Leftrightarrow 2\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+c}}-\frac{9\sqrt{c^2+a^2+2ac}}{8c}<1$

$\Leftrightarrow 2\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+c}}<1+\frac{9\left(a+c\right)}{8c}$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{4a}{a+c}<\frac{81a^2+306ac+289c^2}{64c^2}$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{81a^3+387a^2c+339ac^2+289c^3}{64c^2\left(a+c\right)}>0$

The last inequality is true by $a;c>0$. I want some other way and a inequality is rigider than original inequality. Tks

Answer (score 1):

$2\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+c}}-\frac{9\sqrt{c^2+1}}{8c}=2\sqrt{\frac{a+c-c}{a+c}}-\frac{9\sqrt{a^2+c^2+2ac}}{8c}=2\sqrt{1-\frac c{a+c}}-\frac{9(a+c)}{8c}<2-\frac{9c}{8c}=2-\frac98=\frac78<1$

Comment: Do you have some suggest about a rigid inequality like maximize ?

Comment: I used the inequalities $\sqrt{1-\frac c{a+c}}<1, a+c>c$ which are natural implications of $a,c>0$. What do you mean by rigid inequality? Does it mean an inequality that is true in general?

Comment: It means i want to know the maximize of this inequality.